# How to get first object's element in array of object using ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

How to get first object or specific object's elements value by getting index from elsewhere using ES6

```
arrayOne =[
    { child: [
      {e1: 'ABCD', e2: 'BCDF'}, 
      {e1: '1234', e2: '5689'}, 
      {e1: 'QAZX', e2: 'WESD'}]},
    { child: [
      {e1: 'UHYT', e2: 'QYDG'}, 
      {e1: '9568', e2: '4587'}, 
      {e1: 'ISSF', e2: 'QEIR'}
    ]}
  ]
```

I want output as `arrayTwo = [['ABCD', 'BCDF'], ['1234', '5689'], ['QAZX', 'WESD']]'`

And also how to write dynamic code if anything is changed, like name 'child' or 'e1' or 'e2' is changed.

Comment: Do you want a generic solution or this is the structure you want to code for

Comment: I want code using ES6 to get this output

Comment: what about the second child, do you want to ignore it?

Comment: I want it to be dynamic, I will get index, based on that I have to show output of 1st child or 2nd child

Comment: Though you have asked this question, but i would advice you not write such dynamic code in production , since the chances are more that more properties can be added along with child  with different structure and that will break most dynamic codes.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** You can easily achieve the result using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
arrayOne[0].child.map(({ e1, e2 }) => [e1, e2]);
```

or

```js
const arrayOne = [
  {
    child: [
      { e1: "ABCD", e2: "BCDF" },
      { e1: "1234", e2: "5689" },
      { e1: "QAZX", e2: "WESD" },
    ],
  },
  {
    child: [
      { e1: "UHYT", e2: "QYDG" },
      { e1: "9568", e2: "4587" },
      { e1: "ISSF", e2: "QEIR" },
    ],
  },
];

const result = arrayOne[0].child.map((o) => [o.e1, o.e2]);
console.log(result);
```

**2)** If you want to get all values of `child` array elements(object) in an array then you can make it generic as

```js
const arrayOne = [
  {
    child: [
      { e1: "ABCD", e2: "BCDF" },
      { e1: "1234", e2: "5689" },
      { e1: "QAZX", e2: "WESD" },
    ],
  },
  {
    child: [
      { e1: "UHYT", e2: "QYDG" },
      { e1: "9568", e2: "4587" },
      { e1: "ISSF", e2: "QEIR" },
    ],
  },
];

const result = arrayOne[0].child.map((o) => Object.values(o));
console.log(result);
```

**3)** If the object `key` is not known

```js
const arrayOne = [
  {
    child: [
      { e1: "ABCD", e2: "BCDF" },
      { e1: "1234", e2: "5689" },
      { e1: "QAZX", e2: "WESD" },
    ],
    child2: [
      { e1: "UHYT1", e2: "QYDG1" },
      { e1: "95681", e2: "45871" },
      { e1: "ISSF1", e2: "QEIR1" },
    ],
  },
  {
    child: [
      { e1: "UHYT", e2: "QYDG" },
      { e1: "9568", e2: "4587" },
      { e1: "ISSF", e2: "QEIR" },
    ],
  },
];
const result = Object.values(arrayOne[0]).flatMap((value) => value.map((o) => Object.values(o)));
console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: But what if e1 and e2 are dynamic?

Comment: then you should go for `2` solution. That's the reason I've added 2 solutions

Comment: Ya thanks, I run the code now, but here also if name 'child' is changed then how should i write the code? Can it be more dynamic?

Comment: @R.H No, it can't. Please update your question to show hos `child` can change.

Comment: I mean to say if backend developer changes name child to something else then do I have to change it here also? I was just wondering, is it possible to get more dynamic code?

Comment: Now the `3` code will work even object is dynamic with any `key` and even though there are multiple `keys` like I've added as `child` and `child2`

Comment: your dynmaic program is not giving the correct output

Comment: @vaira which one? `2` or `3`

Comment: 3rd one is returning 6 sub array instead of 3 subarray

Comment: @vaira Just see the source array that I've taken that code snippet. I've used `child` and `child2` 2 objects inside the first element of `arrayOne`

Answer (score 1):

```js
// solution based on index

arrayOne =[
    { child: [
      {e1: 'ABCD', e2: 'BCDF'}, 
      {e1: '1234', e2: '5689'}, 
      {e1: 'QAZX', e2: 'WESD'}]},
    { child: [
      {e1: 'UHYT', e2: 'QYDG'}, 
      {e1: '9568', e2: '4587'}, 
      {e1: 'ISSF', e2: 'QEIR'}
    ]}
  ]
//I want output as based on provided index, where e1, e2 are dynamic
arrayTwo = [['ABCD', 'BCDF'], ['1234', '5689'], ['QAZX', 'WESD']];

const getValueByIndex = (index) => Object.values(arrayOne[index])[0].map(o =>  Object.values(o));
console.log(getValueByIndex(0));
```

Comment: @R.H I think you are looking for this specifically

Comment: But what if e1 and e2 are dynamic?

Comment: you mean dynamic by number of properties or name of properties

Comment: I mean if tomorrow e1 is changed to e5 then what? I dont want to change code again and also child is changed to some other name

Comment: @R.H if child is also dynamic you can use this